# set anchor tag to match full width of parent list item

Tags: html, css

How can I make my anchor match the exact size of the parent list item? Currently it displays the size of the element itself.

Css:

```
ul li a{color: black;background:url(http://mwv3.webs.com/menu_hover.png)-20px bottom no-repeat;
padding:0px 0px 9px 0px;width:100%;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s ease;
     -moz-transition: background .5s ease;
       -o-transition: background .5s ease;
      -ms-transition: background .5s ease;
          transition: background .5s ease;
}

ul li a:hover{
 background:url(http://mwv3.webs.com/menu_hover.png) center bottom 
}
```

Html

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="nav">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe what you're looking for a horizontally displayed, equally distributed unordered list used as a nav bar, and you want the anchor tags to take up 100% of the available space in each list item.  I forked your Fiddle and cleaned up the CSS. See if this helps you: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philnicholas/avLLT/5/)    Note that you *will* have to enter percentages on each list item, in this case 20% for each since there are five (i.e., 100% / 5 = 20% each).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Use This css it will work fine on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/x9FyC/)

```
ul li a{color: black;background:url(http://mwv3.webs.com/menu_hover.png)-20px bottom no-repeat;
    padding:0px 0px 9px 0px;width:100%;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease;
         -moz-transition: background .5s ease;
           -o-transition: background .5s ease;
          -ms-transition: background .5s ease;
              transition: background .5s ease;
    display:block;/*ADDED*/
}

ul li a:hover{

background:url(http://mwv3.webs.com/menu_hover.png) center bottom no-repeat; /*Changed*/
}
```